KDB/q: forEach loop to execute a block of code with a specific parameter
I am trying to make a loop which parses the list and uses each list item inside the loop in the code block but in q lang
I want it to be something like this-
countryList: //list of all countries
for country in countryList:      create csv data(using the country) and store the csv in the specified path
I can't figure out how can i iterate through the list and use it inside a for loop in kdb. I couldn't find anyway to create such a for loop in kdb/q

There is no for loop in kdb+. Have you read this page https://code.kx.com/q/ref/each? It's what you're looking for.

As Cillian mentioned in his comment, each is what you are looking for. You can do the following
{ } each countryList
where { } is a lambda. Or alternatively define your own function
f:{[country]
  // your logic here
}
f each countryList

